# App does not appear in "Apps"

Tags: facebook-apps

I need to update an app. However, I do not see it in the "Apps" list in "Developers".

The app's tab is appearing on the business page, and it appears to be active:

https://www.facebook.com/zapzyt/app_205014796286415

This app has been up well long enough for any previous changes to have "propagated" (the last update was approximately a month ago).

Is there something I'm overlooking? I'm also new to FB apps development, so it's likely something quite simple.

Comment: Are you the owner or collaborator of the app?

Comment: have you access to following url? https://developers.facebook.com/apps/205014796286415/summary